# Using Correct Default g++ Version supporting c++17

Tags: c++, g++, c++17

I had a project that required g++ version 6 or lower (by default). I had deleted versions of g++/gcc multiple times and used `update alternatives` many times.

Currently the project I am working on requires g++7 or higher since it uses c++17. A sample code inside it looks like the following,

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> xyz = std::make_tuple(1, "2");
auto [x, y] = xyz;
std::cout << x << " " << y << "\n";
```

As expected it gives me an error when I run,

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++17
```

It works when I run,

```
g++-7 test.cpp -o test -std=c++17
```

Since my project is large, it is hard to find and replace all g++ with g++-7's. Could anyone please suggest a way how to proceed in this. Currently on running the command `sudo update-alternatives --config g++`, I get the following,

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative g++ (providing /usr/bin/g++).
  Selection    Path            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/g++-7   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/g++-6   50        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/g++-7   80        manual mode
```

[Update] The project uses a single Makefile, and `make cc` is used to compile it. There is no cmake that is used in this project.

Comment: You didn't say how your project is set up. Does it use CMake for instance? Or is it a bunch of hand-written command lines? Can't you just set the environment variable PATH appropriately for each project instead of messing with the system?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. But there is no cmake that is used. It directly runs `make cc`.

Comment: If your makefile used the `g++` command in multiple places, you need to fix. The makefile should say something `CXX=/usr/bin/g++-7` somewhere near the top, and use `$(CXX)` henceforth.

Comment: The simplier way is to use CMake toolchain definition file, and if you are stuck with Unix-Makefile for some reason, emulate it using your own stuff.
See `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/file` and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html

Comment: Saying it uses `make` doesn't tell us much either. Again, a solution that would work in pretty much all cases is you create a directory where you symlink g++-7 as g++, and put it first in PATH before running `make`. But there should be nicer options.

Comment: Is there a dangling g++ somewhere in your path that points to the wrong one? Do "which g++" and see what it points to. This could simply be that your PATH environment variable is set to something that's getting in your way.

Comment: Thank You there was a dangling g++ path in my system. I used soft links in order to fix it and run the project for now.